# pg_ctl says "no server running" when I'm connected to postgres and running queries

Tags: postgresql

**EDIT:** the original question can be found below. Basically, this is a misconception on my part of how `pg_ctl` works and if you're getting this message too (from `pg_ctl`), then the TLDR; is, as @jjanes explains in the accepted answer:

> pg_ctl doesn't track your database. It interacts with a specific directory, either specified by -D, or through the PGDATA env variable.

So the `postgres` you're connected to must have been started somehow, maybe not by you, but was given a `PGDATA` directory to work with.

`pg_ctl` is not your interface to multiple running `postgres` instances.

---

(original question):

I created a directory in `postgres` user's home dir called `mydb`: `/var/lib/postgresql/mydb`

I did this using `initdb -D mydb`.

Now, I want to start `postgres` and use `mydb` as the location where all this db's data is stored; so I run:

```
pg_ctl -D /var/lib/postgresql/mydb start
```

It starts successfully, but if I try:

```
psql (12.6 (Ubuntu 12.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1))
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# show data_directory;
       data_directory        
-----------------------------
 /var/lib/postgresql/12/main
(1 row)
```

i.e. it's using the "main" or default data directory, completely ignoring the `-D` argument.

So now it occurs to me that I might be connecting to a different db... even though running `pg_ctl status` before `pg_ctl start` gives me:

```
pg_ctl: no server running
```

However, this has to be the case because... with "no server running", I am able to `psql` and query the main database.

So then, how do I get the main database "tracked" by `pg_ctl`? Also, how do I use `psql` to connect to the right database?

Thank you

**Edit:** was able to connect to the postgres started with `pg_ctl` using:

```
psql -h /var/run/postgresql
```

(even though I don't see any changes to that directory's contents before / after I `pg_ctl start` i.e. it remains: `12-main.pg_stat_tmp  12-main.pid`).

**Edit:** Also I can see that the postgres process not being tracked by `pg_ctl` was started using `postgres` executable (from running `pstree -a`):

```
postgres -D /var/lib/postgresql/12/main -c config_file=/etc/postgresql/12/main/postgresql.conf
```

Probably from a startup file. I would imagine I need to find this startup file and replace use of `postgres` with `pg_ctl`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pg_ctl doesn't track your database.  It interacts with a specific directory, either specified by -D, or through the PGDATA env variable.  If neither are set, then it throws an error.

```
$ unset PGDATA
$ pg_ctl status
pg_ctl: no database directory specified and environment variable PGDATA unset
Try "pg_ctl --help" for more information.
```

If your database truly did successfully start up, then it either must be configured to run on a non-default port, or it must be configured not to use a port at all but only a unix domain socket.  Neither of these configurations will be set up for you automatically by `initdb`, so I think you may be mistake that it started up in the first place.  Or maybe you did something beyond what you have described to us.

The Unix domain socket is named with a leading `.`, which makes it a hidden file.  You will only see it in /var/run/postgresql with `ls` if you give the `-a` option to it.

What `pg_ctl start` does behind the scenes is call `postgres`, so the database is always started via `postgres`.  It might be directly, or indirectly, or even more indirectly, but eventually that is how it is started.

It is not clear what it is you want to do.  If you want to run out of your own directory, then you probably want to disable the start up script that runs the other one automatically.  On the other hand, why not just use the one that is already configured and managed for you by the packaging system?  You can have both running side by side, buy why?

Comment: Thanks jjanes! I agree that the question is not clear. Mainly, what was bugging me was `pg_ctl` telling me "no server running" when I was connected to postgres and issuing commands. I see now that I had the `PGDATA` env variable set to `~/mydb` and that I was assuming `pg_ctl` was my interface to multiple `postgres` instances. Re "why have multiple instances"? I'm just doing it to learn really. EDIT: I'll try to make the question title clearer.